# Create shortcut on homescreen using ADB

Tags: android, adb

***EDIT: I should add that the author/maintainer of phoneME has - since this question was created - made it possible to add shortcuts in the app itself. So this post isn't relevant anymore.***

I'm running JavaME MIDlets on my Android phone using PhoneME, and it's great.
To run MIDlets, I have to start the Foundation Profile App, and then choose MIDlet to start.

I wish to create shortcuts to the MIDlets from my homescreen using ADB, and have been searching a lot. StackOverflow has a few posts about it, but none that gives a clear answer.
I can't believe it's not possible.

To start a MIDlet on the phone from my PC using ADB, I can type this:

```
./adb shell am start -d file:///sdcard/MyMidlet.jad be.preuveneers.phoneme.fpmidp/.MidletActivity
```

Is there no ADB command that'll create a shortcut on my homescreen to that command line?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have managed to create a shortcut now using this code:

```
Intent shortcut = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shortcut.setClassName("be.preuveneers.phoneme.fpmidp", "be.preuveneers.phoneme.fpmidp.MidletActivity");
shortcut.setData(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/MyMidlet.jad"));

Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "My shortcut");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcut);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now the question is, can the above code be written as an ADB command line? If so, how does that command-line look like?

Thanks

Comment: The "homescreen" is a part of the launcher app. The exact way of adding a new shortcut to it via adb would depend on the exact version of the launcher app on your phone.

Comment: But any launcher receives Intents, right? I have added additional code in my question now. Is there any way that code can be re-written as an ADB command-line?

Comment: generally you can send broadcasts via `adb shell` using the `am broadcast` command. the problem in this case is that you need to create an object first and add it to your intent and there is no way to provide an object as a parameter for `am` command

Comment: instead what you can do (for a specific launcher app) is to add your shortcut record directly to the app's preference file (be it a database or an xml file) and restart the app